# Value of "String" has no member 'indices' - moving to Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm moving from Swift 2 (probably, 2.3) to 3.0 and have a hard time correcting following code :
Now, I know that String is not a collection anymore. How do I correct this particular code?

```
let separator = anyWord.indexOf("-")!

anyWord.substring(with: (anyWord.indices.suffix(from: anyWord.index(anyWord.startIndex, offsetBy: separator + 1))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a possible improvement to [@dfri's first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40483906/2976878), you could use the `upperBound` of `String`'s [`range(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642786-range) method (which is bridged from `NSString`) – which will give you the index after the (first occurrence of the) dash in your string.

```
import Foundation

let anyWord = "foo-bar"

if let separator = anyWord.range(of: "-")?.upperBound {
    let bar = anyWord.substring(from: separator)
    print(bar) // bar
}
```

Or even compacted into a crazy single binding using `Optional`'s [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1539476-map) method:

```
if let bar = (anyWord.range(of: "-")?.upperBound).map(anyWord.substring(from:)) {
    print(bar) // bar
}
```

Although note that the general solution to the problem of 'String not being a collection anymore', is to use `string.characters` instead, which *is* a `Collection`.

Comment: Neat use of `Range`'s `upperBound`!

Answer (score 2):

I'm slightly uncertain as to what you want to achieve, but it seems you'd like, for e.g. a string `foo-bar`, to construct a substring after a given separator, e.g. `bar` given `foo-bar`.

You could achieve this in less complicated fashions than the method you're attempting to implement.

E.g.

```
let anyWord = "foo-bar"

if let separator = anyWord.characters.index(of: "-") {
    let subStartIndex = anyWord.characters.index(after: separator)
    let bar = anyWord[subStartIndex..<anyWord.endIndex]
    print(bar) // bar
}
```

Or, as another alternative, use `Collection`'s [`split(separator:maxSplits:omittingEmptySubsequences:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641547-split) method applied to the `.characters` (collection):

```
let anyWord = "foo-bar"

if let chars = anyWord.characters
    .split(separator: Character("-"), maxSplits: 1)
    .dropFirst(1).last {
    let bar = String(chars)
    print(bar) // bar
}
```

Or, as another alternative, using the [`components(separatedBy: "-")`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1690777-components) method of `String`:

```
import Foundation

let anyWord = "foo-bar"

let bar = anyWord.components(separatedBy: "-").dropFirst(1).reduce("", +)
print(bar) // bar
```

Comment: as only the 1st option fits me , I do : anyWord[anyWord.characters.index(after: separator)..<anyWord.endIndex] but get an error : Type 'String!' has no subscript members