# String and index in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, swift3

here's a part of my code :

```
let separator = anyWord.indexOf("-")!
if (separator >= 0) {
let res = anyWord[anyWord.characters.index(after: separator)..<anyWord.endIndex] //get an error
//some code
}
```

I get an error in 'let res' part - Type 'String!' has no subscript members

if I do  :

```
let separator = anyWord.indexOf("-")!
let subStartIndex = anyWord.characters.index(after: separator)
```

the extension to String :

```
extension String {
    public func indexOf(_ char: Character) -> Int! {
        if let idx = self.characters.index(of: char) {
            return self.characters.distance(from: self.startIndex, to: idx)
        }
        return Const.INVALID_VALUE
    }
```

I get error :

> String may not be indexed with 'Int", it has variable size elements

Comment: Didn't [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40484399/2976878) to your previous question work? Also why have you defined an extension that returns an `Int` index for a `String`? `String`s are subscripted by `String.Index`.

Comment: @Hamish sorry, all this Swift stuff is new to me, and swift 3 created a mess in my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking too complicated, it's pretty easy in Swift 3 using `range(of` and `upperBound`

```
let anyWord = "asdghf-fkgjh"
if let separator = anyWord.range(of:"-") {
   let res = anyWord.substring(from: separator.upperBound)
   //some code
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's my code was auto-converted from Swift 2 and I can't just find such a basic thing as a documentation for a String class.

Comment: ⌥-click on `String` to get the documentation

Comment: thanx ! can you plz tell me more : I have      self.outStr = self.outStr + self.inString.substring(from: self.j) in Swift 3, but self. j is an Int! and not String.Index

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: Then search for solutions here on SO. There are a lot regarding `<String.Index>` and Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to string

```
let test: String
test = "Test-Word"
if let separatorWord = anyWord.range(of: "-") 
{
let word = anyWord.substring(from: anyWord.index(after:   
separatorWord.lowerBound))
print(word)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like 'pure' swift solution ( no Foundation required )

```
let anyWord = "asdghf-fkgjh-blablabla--bla"
anyWord.characters.split(separator: "-").forEach { print( String($0)) }
```

it prints

```
asdghf
fkgjh
blablabla
bla
```